# Схема работы тайлового движка для приложения Mac OS

Tags: разработка-игр, swift, spritekit, tile

Разрабатываю игру на SpriteKit'е с использованием тайлов и столкнулся с проблемой. У меня есть tile map с текстурами 8х8 пикселей, из них собрал изображение локации. При окне размером 640x480 я получаю 80х60 тайлов, которые снижают фреймрейт и при растягивании изображения между ними появляются зазоры. Последнее я исправил добавлением тайлов в отдельную сцену и сохранением её в текстуру. Исходя из собственной логики мне надо сохранить в текстуру те тайлы, которые находятся в зоне видимости и удалить их со сцены после сохранения, а по ходу движения камеры сдвигать текстуру и добавлять к ней новые тайлы и снова сохранять в текстуру. Как это сделать (и можно ли вообще) я пока не знаю и не хотелось бы тратить время на изначально неверный подход. Книги, примеры, туториалы, псевдокод или объяснение "на пальцах" очень помогут

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28951457/efficiently-rendering-tiled-map-using-spritekit

Comment: http://www.sprite-kit.com/opensource/

Comment: это то что надо, спасибо большое

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Немножко информации с SO

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28951457/efficiently-rendering-tiled-map-using-spritekit

Коллекция опенсорсных проектов с использованием спрайт кит

http://sprite-kit.com/opensource

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.